# Error Importing sample projects to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to import this sample project from android so I can study the code however I am getting this error. Anyone know why?

```
 No projects are found to import
```

Comment: Please provide some details like what steps you are following to import android project.

Comment: file ->Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code into workspace->browse

Comment: Probably downloaded file did not contain enough file just only few class file. Try either `Existing Projects into Workspace` or `Existing Android Code Into Workspace`

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is looking for eclipse projects, meaning its is searching for eclipse-specific files in the root directory, namely .project and .classpath. You either gave Eclipse the wrong directory (if you are importing a eclipse project) or you actually want to create a `new project from existing source(new->project->android project from existing source).`

Or `Import -> Android -> Import existing project into workspace`

I think you probably want the second one, because Eclipse projects usually have separate source & build directories. If your sources and .class files are in the same directory, you probably didn't have a eclipse project.

Edit:

```
1) File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace.
2) Select root directory: /path/to/project
3) Projects->Select All
4) UNCHECK both "Copy projects into workspace" and "Add project to working sets"
5) Finish
```

Comment: I do your second suggestion and it says "Select a directory to search for existing Android projects" which makes me think the android example code does not have an eclipse project file to look for?

Comment: If you want to "Create project from existing source", you need to create a new directory and then put the project directory tree into that new directory. Then point to the new directory when importing

Answer (score 0):

```
Goto File -> Import -> Android -> Import existing project into workspace
```

Import the project in above method it will works .. baby

Answer (score 0):

Yupe, you are importing the android code which is not having the AndrodiManifest.xml file. so instead of importing "existig project into the workspace" you need to import Android Code into the workspace.

Eclipse

```
File->New->Project->Android Project from Existing code->browse
```

Answer (score 0):

**Have a look at It:**

- Goto File > New > Project
- Select the type of project, click Next
- Uncheck Use default location
- Click on Browse to navigate to your source folder, or type in the
  path to your source
- Click Finish

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

File -> import -> General -> Existing Project in Workplace - > Browse